# Parse XML to ListView Windows Metro

Tags: xml, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app for windows 8.1. I was able to parse XML file to ListView. It is local XML file, but when I put XML path (XMLFile1.xml) as an URL (for example http://192.168.x.x/test.xml) it gives me an error.
This is my code.

XAML file:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="373" Margin="1229,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

XAML.cs file:

```
public class Person
        {
            string firstname;
            string lastname;
            int age;

            public string FirstName
            {
                get { return firstname; }
                set { firstname = value; }
            }

            public string LastName
            {
                get { return lastname; }
                set { lastname = value; }
            }

            public int Age
            {
                get { return age; }
                set { age = value; }
            }
        }
        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string peopleXMLPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "XMLFile1.xml");
            XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(peopleXMLPath);

            var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("person")
                       select new Person
                       {
                           FirstName = (string)query.Element("firstname"),
                           LastName = (string)query.Element("lastname"),
                           Age = (int)query.Element("age")
                       };
            listView1.ItemsSource = data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list the code you are using when attempting to load the data via an external source. If you have not changed this, then try the option below.

Try changing

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(peopleXMLPath);
```

to

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("http://192.168.x.x/test.xml");
```

Comment: Error again. It gives me "An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code" :/

Comment: EDIT 2: It give me error on local network unfortunately. I tried this: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml and it worked on external but not my XML file. :/ Anyway thank you. :)

Comment: The IP address seems like a broadband router IP address. You're going to have all sorts of issues trying to get your emulator to resolve it. I usually just host such files as an azure blob with xml mime type for testing.

Comment: The logic I want to use is this...
I generate XML File from SQL Server database. then I want to copy XML data to Local DB on my app, like SQLite. More or like syncing.
That's why I use local IP. And for the app to connect with this local IP, the tablet will be connected through a VPN. I do not want the data to be in public domain.